# TextView align with two lines

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I put `TextView` in a layout with const string. the string is long so i define two lines `TextView` . the problem is that the second line start from the right instead from the center. how i can to align the `TextView` to be from the center

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_item"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:lines="2" android:textColor="@color/Red"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it s the [gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:gravity) attribute

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_item"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:lines="2" android:textColor="@color/Red"/>
```

Could you try this? Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

adding `android:gravity="center"` will work